# Is the JSON object global in Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js

I can't seem to find the documentation on JSON.parse(...) for Node.js. I just see it littered around various scripts. I was wondering, where does it come from - are there certain callbacks that make it available or is it a global object?

Thanks!
Matt Mueller

Comment: here's a link to their implementation: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#W9JxUuHYyMg/trunk/src/json.js&l=229

Comment: @generalhenry you should(I think) post your comments as answers so that this topic can be closed/acccepted.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's built into V8.

Here's a link to their implementation: http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/json.js