# Three on node.js with JSONLoader

Tags: node.js, three.js, collision

I need to use three.js on my node.js server to control positions and collisions on players (I try to make a video game).

To use three on nodejs, I have install with "npm install three", and it's works.

But when I want call JSONLoader, I can't.

I my class, I add :

```
var THREE =require('three'); //or require('three/three.js');
var JSON=require('three/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js');
```

or

```
require('three'); //or require('three/three.js');
var JSON=require('three/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js');
```

It the same, I have an error, "THREE is not defined" and I don't undestand why?

To resolve this error i put the JSON code in the three.js file, but I find an other problem when I load json:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load(__dirname + '/public/js/essai/test.dae',function ( collada ){
...
});
Error : XMLHttpRequest is not defined.
```

I think, I don't use correctly but I don't undestand where is my fault?

Can you help me plz?

Thank you very much.

Comment: One thing you probably don't want to do is declare a variable named `JSON`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857072/is-the-json-object-global-in-node-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the socond line, i.e.

```
var JSON = require('three/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js');
```

If you load `three.js` properly, so e.g.

```
var THREE = require('three/three.js')
```

the `JSONLoader` is already there, so `THREE.JSONLoader` should work just fine.

**BTW**, the reason why you're getting this error is because the code of `JSONLoader.js` depends on existance of `THREE` object in the global scope. But, it's not there because your `THREE` object is local.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to your help.

I replace my code, indeed it's works better, i don't know why I have had JSONLoader.js into variable.

However, I have my second problem. This code run at reception to a socket in node.js.

```
Room.prototype.create = function(data, socket, emit)
    {
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(__dirname + '/public/js/essai/test.js',function ( collada ){
                        console.log(collada);
                    }); 
}
```

But my error is :

```
ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
    at THREE.JSONLoader.loadAjaxJSON (C:\wamp\www\SiteThreeOnNode\kart\node_modu
les\three\three.js:9974:16)
    at THREE.JSONLoader.load (C:\wamp\www\SiteThreeOnNode\kart\node_modules\thre
e\three.js:9968:7)
    at C:\wamp\www\SiteThreeOnNode\kart\routes\room.js:37:12
```

After search, i have try to replace url json by `http://localhost:2999/js/essai/test.js` like this : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally
And I have acces to my json with this url.

But XMLHttpRequest is not defined, so it's change nothing, I think it's because I try to do this with a socket function but i'm not sure.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` won't work server side. What you actually need to do is to obtain the `json` file somehow (look [here](https://gist.github.com/cjoudrey/988107) for example) and then use `JSONLoader.parse` method (look [here] for documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I have a last one question.
In node server I load .json file and put in to the scene to detect collisions.

Node:

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public/js/essai/lobby.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    return;
                  }

                  data = JSON.parse(data);
                  var model = loader.parse( data );
                  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
                  mesh.scale.set(40,40,40);
                  scene.add( mesh );
                  collisable.push( mesh );
    });
```

To detect collision :

```
var collisions, i,
            // Maximum distance from the origin before we consider collision
            distance = 32,
            // Get the obstacles array from our world
            obstacles = GameEngine.getInstance().collidableMeshList;//basicScene.world.getObstacles();
        // For each ray
        for (i = 0; i < this.rays.length; i += 1) {
            // We reset the raycaster to this direction
            this.caster.set(this.design.position, this.rays[i]);
            // Test if we intersect with any obstacle mesh
            collisions = this.caster.intersectObjects(obstacles);
            // And disable that direction if we do
            if (collisions.length > 0 && collisions[0].distance <= distance) {
                // Yep, this.rays[i] gives us : 0 => up, 1 => up-left, 2 => left, ...
                if ((i === 0 || i === 1 || i === 7) && this.direction.z === 1) {
                   console.log("collisions"); //
                } else if ((i === 3 || i === 4 || i === 5) && this.direction.z === -1) {
                   console.log("collisions");
                }
                if ((i === 1 || i === 2 || i === 3) && this.direction.x === 1) {
                    console.log("collisions");
                } else if ((i === 5 || i === 6 || i === 7) && this.direction.x === -1) {
                    console.log("collisions");
                }
            }
        }
```

When I have try collision on the client , it's work fine, but on the server, he doesn't detect collisions.
So, I have try to load json file in my client to see if the load is correctly.

When I load like this in my Client, the scene is ok:

```
loader.load( "essai/lobby.js", function( geometry ) {
     mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
      mesh.scale.set( 40, 40, 40 );
      scene.add(mesh);
      animate();
});
```

And when I load like this in Client, it's not ok:

```
$.getJSON("essai/lobby.js", function(data) {
      var model = loader.parse( data );
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
      mesh.scale.set(40,40,40);
      scene.add(mesh);
      animate();
      });
```

No error, but nothing appear.

So I think is the same to the server side, and why collisions are never detect.

In the server side, I don't use animate() , because I think it's not necessary.
And the calcul to deplace my car it's ok.

So I think maybe the loader don't load the mesh correctly, or I can't make detection collisions as on Client.
What do you think?

Thx.

To detect collisions on Client I use:

```
this.rays = [
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), //up
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1), //up left
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), //left
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -1), // down left
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1), //down
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -1), // down right
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), //rigth
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 1) //up right
        ];
        this.caster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

When I up, I set the direction : this.direction.set(0,0,1);
When I down,I set the direction : this.direction.set(0,0,-1);
...

Comment: First, I think that if you want to ask another question you should post a new question, not an answer :) Second, if I were you, I would check - somehow - whether my model loads properlly on the server. Maybe use some console listings or something of this type.

Comment: Ok, I will try. If I don't find, I will create a new question with more explain.