# three.js collisions on node.js with jsonloader

Tags: json, node.js, three.js, collision-detection

I have a last one question.
In node server I load .json file and put in to the scene to detect collisions.

Node:

```
 var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    fs.readFile(__dirname+'/public/js/essai/lobby.js', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.log('Error: ' + err);
                    return;
                  }

                  data = JSON.parse(data);
                  var model = loader.parse( data );
                  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
                  mesh.scale.set(40,40,40);
                  scene.add( mesh );
                  collisable.push( mesh );
    });
```

To detect collision :

```
var collisions, i,
            // Maximum distance from the origin before we consider collision
            distance = 32,
            // Get the obstacles array from our world
            obstacles = GameEngine.getInstance().collidableMeshList;//basicScene.world.getObstacles();
        // For each ray
        for (i = 0; i < this.rays.length; i += 1) {
            // We reset the raycaster to this direction
            this.caster.set(this.design.position, this.rays[i]);
            // Test if we intersect with any obstacle mesh
            collisions = this.caster.intersectObjects(obstacles);
            // And disable that direction if we do
            if (collisions.length > 0 && collisions[0].distance <= distance) {
                // Yep, this.rays[i] gives us : 0 => up, 1 => up-left, 2 => left, ...
                if ((i === 0 || i === 1 || i === 7) && this.direction.z === 1) {
                   console.log("collisions"); //
                } else if ((i === 3 || i === 4 || i === 5) && this.direction.z === -1) {
                   console.log("collisions");
                }
                if ((i === 1 || i === 2 || i === 3) && this.direction.x === 1) {
                    console.log("collisions");
                } else if ((i === 5 || i === 6 || i === 7) && this.direction.x === -1) {
                    console.log("collisions");
                }
            }
        }
```

When I have try collision on the client , it's work fine, but on the server, he doesn't detect collisions.
So, I have try to load json file in my client to see if the load is correctly.

When I load like this in my Client, the scene is ok:

```
loader.load( "essai/lobby.js", function( geometry ) {
     mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
      mesh.scale.set( 40, 40, 40 );
      scene.add(mesh);
      animate();
});
```

And when I load like this in Client, it's not ok:

```
$.getJSON("essai/lobby.js", function(data) {
      var model = loader.parse( data );
      var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( model.geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() );
      mesh.scale.set(40,40,40);
      scene.add(mesh);
      animate();
      });
```

No error, but nothing appear.

So I think is the same to the server side, and why collisions are never detect.

In the server side, I don't use animate() , because I think it's not necessary.
And the calcul to deplace my car it's ok.

So I think maybe the loader don't load the mesh correctly, or I can't make detection collisions as on Client.
What do you think?

Thx.

To detect collisions on Client I use:

```
this.rays = [
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), //up
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 1), //up left
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, 0), //left
                new THREE.Vector3(1, 0, -1), // down left
                new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, -1), //down
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, -1), // down right
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 0), //rigth
                new THREE.Vector3(-1, 0, 1) //up right
        ];
        this.caster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.direction = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
```

When I up, I set the direction : this.direction.set(0,0,1);
When I down,I set the direction : this.direction.set(0,0,-1);
...

Update:
After many tests, collisions detect an object.
I have find Mesh are the same in server side or client, but the scale of json object after load aren't considered!

So I have try to make a scene.updateMatrix() in my node.js server after load and change scale, but It's the same.

Have you any ideas to resolve my problem?

Comment: well, it's a bit difficult to figure what's going on here. my 2 cents: check the parsed json is the same on both sides, look at numbers formats specifically; also, some three.js computations are done once meshes are rendered, so you should animate/render them just as the client do, just to be sure. HTH

Comment: adding some debugging statements in your `loaders/JSONLoader.js` and `loaders/Loader.js` could also help figure it out.

Comment: Thx, I have try to check, but I don't see the difference of mesh. I have try to send mesh of my server to my client to see the renderer but I have a circular error with json. I will try to debug more. Do you think, I can use ColladaLoader of the folder "example" to the module three.js in node.js, because I can't load this file with require()? (to try with a .dae file)

Comment: Should be possible, but you'll run into the same issues as discussed in your other question, here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455087/three-on-node-js-with-jsonloarder/19477059#19477059 (you need to read the file, then parse it manually)